# Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

So I try to import sql file into rds (1G MEM, 1 CPU). The sql file is like 1.4G

mysql -h xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -u user -ppass --max-allowed-packet=33554432 db < db.sql

It got stuck at:

```
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 374: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

The actual sql content is:

```
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`another_user`@`1.2.3.4`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `change_log_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `change_log` FOR EACH ROW
IF (NEW.created_at IS NULL OR NEW.created_at = '00-00-00 00:00:00' OR NEW.created_at = '') THEN
        SET NEW.created_at = NOW();
END IF */;;
```

`another_user` is not existed in rds, so I do:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO another_user@'localhost';
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 369, accepted):

Either remove the `DEFINER=..` statement from your sqldump file, or replace the user values with `CURRENT_USER`.

The MySQL server provided by RDS does not allow a `DEFINER` syntax for another user (in my experience).

You can use a `sed` script to remove them from the file:

```
sed 's/\sDEFINER=`[^`]*`@`[^`]*`//g' -i oldfile.sql
```

Comment: You're correct.  The reason it doesn't work is that specifying another user as `DEFINER` when the logged-in user does not have the `SUPER` privilege (which itself is not allowed in RDS) would allow arbitrary privilege escalation -- stored programs run with the credentials and privileges of their `DEFINER` (as opposed to those of the calling user -- their `INVOKER`), by default.  Also [at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/555983/153161).

Comment: For some reason I had to use * instead of +: ````sed 's/\sDEFINER=`[^`]*`@`[^`]*`//'  -i oldfile.sql````

Comment: The `+` is not valid in standard sed. `sed -E` also works, but I don't see any harm in changing it to `*` anyway.

Comment: is there any faster option ? sed is kind of slow if the sql file is very big

Comment: @WonderLand You can try `awk` which might be a little faster than `sed`

Comment: if it easy/fast for you ... do you mind improve your answer adding an `awk` example too ?

Comment: @WonderLand I haven't used `awk` much. I just read online [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/311546) that sed is slower than awk.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me. Another potential solution from aws doc:  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/error-1227-mysqldump/

Comment: The RDS export I had had double quotes instead of backticks.

`/s\sDEFINER="[^`]*"@"[^`]*"//g` works on this type.

Comment: @trainoasis osx uses a different version of sed/grep etc. tools. Please check the man pages for relevant commands in osx `sed`.

Comment: For some reason the sed.exe that comes with Git Bash tools doesn't seem to like character classes - to get around this I used this regex instead: `sed 's/ DEFINER=\`\w*\`@\`\w*\`//g' -i oldfile.sql`

Answer (score 330):

Remove the 3 lines below if they're there, or comment them out with `--` :

At the start:

```
-- SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;
-- SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/*!80000 '+'*/ '';
```

At the end:

```
-- SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN = @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN;
```

Note that the comment characters are "dash dash space" including the space.

A better solution is to stop these lines from being written to the dump file at all by including the option `--set-gtid-purged=OFF` on your `mysqldump` command.

Comment: You can prevent these by adding `--set-gtid-purged=OFF` to your `mysqldump` command. Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56251925

Comment: @IllyaMoskvin this is what worked for me. Upon Date Export in my sql workbench --> Advanced Options -->  set-gtid-purged - Add 'SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED' to the output --> set to "OFF"

Comment: I get `mysqldump: unknown variable 'set-gtid-purged=OFF'` in MariaDB 10.3

Comment: This solution worked perfect for me on mysql8 hosted on AWS RDS. Thanks

Answer (score 79):

Another useful trick is to invoke mysqldump with the option `--set-gtid-purged=OFF` which does not write the following lines to the output file:

```
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;
SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/*!80000 '+'*/ '';
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN = @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN;
```

not sure about the DEFINER one.

Comment: Thank you. In my case I ran `SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_MODE = OFF;` in MySql Workbench in the exporting side from source database

Comment: I have deleted these two lines from the dump file then it works for me   --SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;
SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/*!80000 '+'*/ '';

Comment: thank you.
I solved it by specifying `--set-gtid-purged=OFF` in MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 29):

When we create a new RDS DB instance, the default master user is not the root user. But only gets certain privileges for that DB instance. This permission does not include **SET** permission. Now if your default master user tries to execute mysql **SET** commands, then you will face this error: **Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation**

#### Solution 1

Comment out or remove these lines

```
SET @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN = @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN;
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 1;
SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/*!80000 '+'*/ '';
```

#### Solution 2

You can also ignore the errors by using the -f option to load the rest of the dump file.

```
mysql -f <REPLACE_DB_NAME> -u <REPLACE_DB_USER> -h <DB_HOST_HERE> -p < dumpfile.sql
```

Comment: Solution 2 works well if you are piping a mysqldump to a new database

Answer (score 22):

Just a MacOS extra update for hjpotter92 answer.

To make `sed` recognize the pattern in MacOS, you'll have to add a backslash before the `=` sign, like this:

```
sed -i old 's/\DEFINER\=`[^`]*`@`[^`]*`//g' file.sql
```

Answer (score 15):

**Problem**: You're trying to import data (using mysqldump file) to your mysql database ,but it seems you don't have permission to perform that operation.

**Solution**: Assuming you data is migrated ,seeded and updated in your mysql database, take snapshot using mysqldump and export it to file

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [databaseName] --set-gtid-purged=OFF > [filename].sql
```

> *From mysql documentation:*
>
> **GTID** -  A global transaction identifier (GTID) is a unique identifier created
>   and associated with each transaction committed on the server of origin
>   (master). This identifier is unique not only to the server on which it
>   originated, but is unique across all servers in a given replication
>   setup. There is a 1-to-1 mapping between all transactions and all
>   GTIDs.
>
> **--set-gtid-purged=OFF** SET @@GLOBAL.gtid_purged is not added to the output, and SET
>   @@SESSION.sql_log_bin=0 is not added to the output. For a server where
>   GTIDs are not in use, use this option or AUTO. Only use this option
>   for a server where GTIDs are in use if you are sure that the required
>   GTID set is already present in gtid_purged on the target server and
>   should not be changed, or if you plan to identify and add any missing
>   GTIDs manually.

Afterwards connect to your mysql with user root ,give permissions , flush them ,and verify that your user privileges were updated correctly.

```
mysql -u root -p
UPDATE mysql.user SET Super_Priv='Y' WHERE user='johnDoe' AND host='%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'johnDoe';
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for johnDoe                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `johnDoe`                                  |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db1`.* TO `johnDoe`                     |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

now reload the data and **the operation should be permitted**.

```
mysql -h [host] -u [user] -p[pass] [db_name] < [mysql_dump_name].sql
```

Answer (score 11):

### **Full Solution**

All the above solutions are fine. And here I'm gonna combine all the solutions so that it should work for all the situations.

1. **Fixed DEFINER**

*For Linux and Mac*

```
sed -i old 's/\DEFINER\=`[^`]*`@`[^`]*`//g' file.sql
```

*For Windows*
download atom or notepad++, open your dump sql file with atom or notepad++, press Ctrl+F
search the word **DEFINER**, and remove the line **DEFINER=`admin`@`%`** (or may be little different for you) from everywhere and save the file.
As for example
before removing that line: *CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `MyProcedure`*
After removing that line: *CREATE PROCEDURE `MyProcedure`*

1. **Remove the 3 lines**
   Remove all these 3 lines from the dump file. You can use *sed* command or open the file in Atom editor and search for each line and then remove the line.
   Example: Open Dump2020.sql in Atom, Press ctrl+F, search *SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0*, remove that line.

```
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;
SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/*!80000 '+'*/ '';
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN = @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN;
```

2. **There an issue with your generated file**
   You might face some issue if your generated dump.sql file is not proper. But here, I'm not gonna explain how to generate a dump file. But you can ask me (*_*)

Answer (score 5):

**Issue**

Below statement or line your Dump file creating issue

> DEFINER=`username`@`%

**Simple Solution**

The solution that you can workaround is to remove all the entries from **SQL** dump file and import data from the **GCP console**.

```
 cat DUMP_FILE_NAME.sql |  sed -e 's/DEFINER=`<username>`@`%`//g' > NEW-CLEANED-DUMP.sql
```

above command will help to remove all those lines from the dump file and create the new fresh dump file without **Definer**.

**Try importing new file**(NEW-CLEANED-DUMP.sql).

If you are on **AWS RDS**

You might see face issue, if your dump file is larger you can check the first 20 lines using

```
head -30 filename
```

once you can see output look for line and line number

```
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;
SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/*!80000 '+'*/ '';
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN = @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN;
```

we will remove these lines by line numbers for example 17,18,24 line number

```
sed -e '24d;17d;18d' file-name.sql > removed-line-file-name.sql
```

Answer (score 4):

For importing database file in `.sql.gz` format, remove definer and import using below command

```
zcat path_to_db_to_import.sql.gz | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' | mysql -u user -p new_db_name
```

1. Earlier, export database in .sql.gz format using below command.

   `mysqldump -u user -p old_db | gzip -9 > path_to_db_exported.sql.gz;`
2. Import that exported database and removing definer using below command,

   `zcat path_to_db_exported.sql.gz | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' | mysql -u user -p new_db`

Answer (score 3):

I commented all the lines start with `SET` in the `*.sql` file and it worked.

Comment: nice man, really descriptive. youre doing a great job

Answer (score 3):

When you restore backup, Make sure to try with the same username for the old one and the new one.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, when I tried to restore a DB dump on my AWS MySQL RDS, I got this error:

```
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 18: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, 
SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
```

I didn't have to change the DEFINER or remove/comment out lines. I just did:

```
GRANT SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN ON *.* TO myuser@'myhost';
GRANT SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN ON *.* TO myuser@'myhost';
```

And I was able to do the restore.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked for me. I had to do the following:

- Use the following flags with `mysqldump`:

  ```sh
  mysqldump --databases <db1> <db2> --master-data=1 --single-transaction --order- 
  by-primary --foce -r all.sql -h<host> -u<user> -p<password>
  ```
- Remove the line that looks like:

  ```sh
  CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='binlog.....
  ```

  - In my file, that was line #22, so I ran: `sed -i '22d' all.sql`
- Import the data to your RDS:

  ```
  mysql -h<host> -u<user> -p<password>
  $ source all.sql
  ```

Comment: Did your dump still contain the three SET lines that all the other solutions say we have to delete?  I can't see how these flags will make a difference

Answer (score 1):

In my case (trying to execute a SQL file into **AWS RDS**) the beginning of my SQL statement looked like this:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `something_view`;
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `something_view`...
```

All I had to do to fix it was to remove `ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER='root'@'%' SQL SECURITY DEFINER` part of the above statement.

So the new statement looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW 'something_view' ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest Soluction
login: aws rds/ or other mysql server and assign required permissions, run below commands(you can change username and host)

```
GRANT SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN ON *.* TO root@'%';
GRANT SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN ON *.* TO root@'%';
```

Comment: little changes to the @Ram' suggestion for the beginners
(1.) Open terminal
(2.) login to ads using 
`mysql --protocol=tcp --host=<your_db_instance_hostname> --user=<your_username> --password=<your_password>--port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8`
(3.) `GRANT SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN ON *.* TO root@'%';`
(4.) `GRANT SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN ON *.* TO root@'%';`

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

*** Answer may only be applicable to MacOS ***

When trying to import a .sql file into a docker container, I encountered the error message:

> Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for
>   this operation

Then while trying some of the other suggestions, I received the below error on my MacOS (osx)

> sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence

Finally, the following command from this [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x) resolved my "Access Denied" issue.

```
LC_ALL=C sed -i old 's/\DEFINER\=`[^`]*`@`[^`]*`//g' fileName.sql
```

So I could import into the docker database with:

```
docker exec -i dockerContainerName mysql -uuser -ppassword table < importFile.sql
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue in dump.

Please try to get dump by following way:

```
mysqldump -h databasehost --user=databaseusername --password --single-transaction databasename  | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' | gzip > /tmp/database.sql.gz
```

Then, try to import by following way:

```
zcat /tmp/database.sql.gz | mysql -h database_host -u username -p databasename
```

Answer (score 0):

**My Problem:** I want to dump the database from A provider to restore a database on the database cluster on B provider with MySQL version 8 both via DBeaver.

**Solution:** I follow this step was worked. I hope this solution will help you.

1. Backup database with additional option - `Remove DEFINER`

[image: Backup_DB_DBeaver]

2. Assign GRANT permission

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON [database_name].* TO '[database_user]'@'[database_host]';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

3. Restore database with sql dump file, you will found this error

> Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation

4. Go to sql dump file, comment this line and save it

```
SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/*!80000 '+'*/;
```

[image: SQL_Dump_File]

5. Restore database to destination server again

Answer (score 0):

Some SET statements might require privileges,so you can try removing them:

```
sed -i '/^SET/d' dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can grant `SET_USER_ID` to the user which is running the import on a mysql RDS instance:
`GRANT SET_USER_ID ON *.* TO 'import_user'@'%';`

then you can run:
`mysql -h xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -u import_user -ppass db < db.sql`

SET_USER_ID from mysql [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_set-user-id):

> A user with this privilege can specify any account as the DEFINER attribute of a view or stored program

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is having a hard time trying to run Djando. I've found the inconvenience in seetings.py mysql connection

```
"OPTIONS": {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', innodb_strict_mode=1"
}
```

Give the permissions for your MYSQL user, (i don't
really know if it the correct solution but it works for me...)

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score -1):

Need to set "on" server parameter "log_bin_trust_function_creators" on server side. This one you can easily find on left side blade if it is azure maria db.