# Getting error while creating trigger in RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I was getting error while creating a trigger in RDS as it was asking me to have super privilege. I change the value of parameter "log_bin_trust_function_creators" to 1 and now I am getting the following error.
Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation .

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Can you paste the syntax you used ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015692/access-denied-you-need-at-least-one-of-the-super-privileges-for-this-operat)